# Do I need to add a second well pump pressure tank?

Tags: plumbing

Our house has a private well for water supply. We have a constant pressure well pump and we have a small pressure tank where the water line comes into the house.  I have a large shop I built that I had plumbed for a full bathroom. There is a 1" water line that runs from the house out to the shop. The water line out to the shop sits after the expansion tank and water filtration system. My question is, I am planning the plumbing in the shop and was wondering if I need to put a second expansion tank out in the shop or if the one on the house is sufficient.

Comment: Believe a second expansion tank would work against the first, you want the pressure to be behind the water.  Might want a larger water tank if the one you have is too small for the house and shop to be used(using water) at the same time.

Comment: Are we talking about expansion tanks or pressure tanks, they are quite different and used for different purposes. Very unlikely you'd need another expansion tank.   

Once again, I'll say "all wells are different", if you have a low producing well, large pressure tanks are your friend.  

A 1" line is pretty good sized for a shop, it will flow a LOT of water **IF** you can supply it via a high capacity well.  If low capacity well, yeah, another large pressure tank in the shop would be a good idea.

Comment: Since you are doing the plumbing run a connection to your new small bladder tank but put a shutoff valve and do not install the tank. With the filters It would be a guess as to whether you really need it. Using the system in the future will tell you for sure if you need it. If you add the tank it will effect both ends, the shop and home.